# Console-like control that allows full control over individual text formatting

Tags: c#, winforms, text

I'm tinkering with writing a simple text-based role-playing game. I would like to use WinForms, and utilize WinForm controls for the UI and simple text for the output. The catch is, I would like to have complete control over the formatting of the individual text - some words being different colors, etc. A simple console control would suffice, as that would provide control over text colors, but it would be nice to also be able to change style, font and size.

Less important: it would be nice to have complete control over where text appears in the control through a coordinate system, as with DOS windows of old.

I'd appreciate suggestions on the best method of implementing this. Perhaps there is a better method I had not considered for rendering the output of a text-based game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm... maybe you could use or adapt a `RichTextBox` or a `WebBrowser` control for this purpose?

Comment: Both sound like workable options. Is there any overhead from having an excessive amount of HTML markup in a scrollable WebBrowser window? One additional factor would be that the WB window would offer the ability of hyper linking within the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have complete control by overriding the OnPaint() method.  Use TextRenderer.DrawText() to get it exactly the way you want it.